# How to access id passed via onclick in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been looking from an hour but no luck, I have an JavaScript on-click function on HTML tag. The on-click function redirects me to an another page. The content on the other page will depends on the id passed in the JavaScript on-click event. The problem is I don't know how to access the id in my PHP file so that I can run SQL query to display the data. I don't want the id to be displayed in the URL either.

My HTML on-click element:

```
<h1 onclick="ContentPage(this.id)" value='.$id.'>'.$title.'</h1>
```

My javasript function:

```
<script>
function ContentPage(){

    location.href = "show-content.php";
};
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use inline js / css - it's bad practice that leads to hard to maintain code. Also, you need to research $.post or $.ajax. on php side, research $_POST and $_GET

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, thank you I'll make sure to avoid this as much as possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways you can go...

#### Based on your current approach--

Modify your function as such:

```
function ContentPage(id){
    location.href = "show-content.php?id="+id;
}
```

The value of id will be in the `$_GET` variable; specifically of index `id`

so on your page page,

```
$passedId = $_GET['id'];
```

#### Another approach -- not using inline `JS` --

```
<h1 id="myTitle_'.$id.'" class="clickNavigate" value='.$id.'>'.$title.'</h1>
```

then your JavaScript code becomes

```
jQuery(".clickNavigate").on("click", function(e) {
    var myID = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    var idParts = myID.split("_");

    location.href = "show-content.php?id="+idParts[1];

});
```

Comment: oh thankyou, but as mentioned by@ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs this is a bad practice to have inline js I have tried to implement click event with jquery but that doesn't work can you help me with that. I will really appreciate that.

Comment: Thank you so much @Rushikumar

Comment: @samscoot glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Fast example using GET, you can also use POST

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

HTML

```
<h1 onclick="ContentPage(this)" value='.$id.' id="myid">'.$title.'</h1>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
function ContentPage(elem){
    location.href = "show-content.php" + "?id=" + elem.value;
};
</script>
```

PHP

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is send the id using javascript in the URL to a new page like this:

```
<script>
function ContentPage(elem){
    location.href = "random-page.php?id=" + value;
};
</script>
```

Then on that page, GET the id from the URL and then POST it to your actual page using a form. This way on the actual page, you can use $_POST to retrieve it, without it showing up in the URL.

Random-page.php:

```
    $id = $_GET["id"];

    <html>
      <form id='form1' name='myform' action='show-content.php' method='POST' >
        <input type='text' value='<?php echo $id; ?>' name='id' hidden />
        <input type='submit' name='myform' />
      </form>


      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('form1').submit(); // SUBMIT FORM
      </script>
    </html>
```

On show-content.php, do this to get the id:

```
if(isset($_POST['myform'])){
  $id = $_POST['id'];
}
```

It's a bit complex, but worth a try if you want a quick solution without AJAX, etc.